# Duplicate figure(1) and assign the duplicate to figure(2)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created the following figure (figure(1)) in Matlab.

[image: figure(1)]

I am trying to create a figure(2), which is going be exactly the same as figure(1) - in other words duplicate the figure(1) and the duplicate version I want to assign it as figure(2).

The reason for that is that I want to be able to present the figure(1) as it is and then in figure(2) I want to present only part of the figure(1) (for example the part for which the x is between 0.333 and 0.666).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
copyobj(gcf, groot)
```

This creates a copy ([`copyobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html)) of the current figure ([`gcf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html)), including its children, as a new child of the graphics root object ([`groot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html)).